# my website logout button only doing logout from website not from the facebook?

Tags: php

my website  logout button only doing logout from website not from the facebook?
I am using facebook php sdk 4 for my application.

I am doing the facebook login and logout from a website. So if a user wants to login into the site he will click on facebook login and when he will click on logout then he will automatically logout from both facebook and from the site as well.

Comment: You might want to add some code to your question to show how you're doing logout, because there's no way to answer this as it stands.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `getLogoutUrl()` to get logout url from facebook and after destroying session of your website call the url returned by facebook.

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
    'next'  => 'url to which facebook should redirect after logout.'
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the logout event is triggered when clicking your logout button. There are a few ways to do this, for example:

```
// Add onclick property directly to UI element markup
<input type="button" value="Logout" **onclick="FB.logout();">

// Use an event delegate
$('input[value="Logout"]').bind('click', function() {
  if ($(this).attr('value') === "Logout") {
    FB.logout();
  }
);
```

If you're still having trouble, subscribe to the logout event to debug:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', logout_event);

FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```